# Movie References? Question about Lucy

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is it alright to ask a question about the movie reference of a drug, only because the producer claims it to be real?

**Question** in Question:

[Does CPH4 exists?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20387/does-cph4-exists?lq=1)

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20410/whats-the-name-of-this-molecule-if-it-exists

Comment: just for humor: if the producer knew that such a drug exists and knows how it works then he must have tried it once.. he should have been making much better movies if such a drug was really available..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should not keep questions with so little backup (like one man's claim). They are good questions, but would be a far better fit for Skeptics.se. When someone has actual evidence of a molecule, and wants the name, that's different.

So, basically, closing was the right thing to do, but I personally would have flagged them for migration to Skeptics as well, so that the users who asked them get a good answer, rather than a 'closed as off topic'.